# Porque me posiciona pegados estos dos divs?

Tags: html, html5

Estoy realizando un formulario con clases de bootstrap y me posiciona dos divs uno arriba del otro pegados y nose porque, nunca me sucedio algo asi y no estoy utilizando ningun tipo de hoja de estilos, solamente clases de bootsrap.

```html
                     <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                          <label for="lab1">Laboratorio 1</label>
                          <select name="lab1" class="form-control select2" >
                          <option value="">Seleccionar </option>
                          <option value="Superi">1. Superi</option>
                          <option value="Guerra">2. Guerra</option>
                          <option value="RF Technologies">3. RF Technologies</option>
                          <option value="Ricardo">4. Ricardo</option> 
                          <option value="Tecno-int">5. Tecno-int</option>
                          <option value="Dyxa">6. Dyxa</option>  
                        </div>
                          
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                          <label for="deliver">Fecha de Devolucion</label>
                          <input type="text" name="deliver" id="deliver" class="form-control form-control-sm" required placeholder="Entrega al Cliente" readonly>
                        </div>
                          
                          
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                          <label for="change_type1">Tipo de cambio</label>
                          <input type="number"   step="00.01" name="change_type1" id="change_type1"  class="form-control" >
                        </div>                    
                                      
                       
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                           <label for="cost_lab">Costo de laboratorio 1 (USD-O)</label>
                           <input type="number"   step="00.01" id="cost_lab" name="cost_lab" class="form-control"  >
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                          <label for="cost_labARS">Costo de laboratorio 1 (ARS)</label>
                          <input type="number"   step="00.01" id="cost_labARS" name="cost_labARS" class="form-control"  >
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Eso es por que no has cerrado el `SELECT`aun.

Siempre recuerda revisar tus llaves y cierres.

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <label for="lab1">Laboratorio 1</label>
  <select name="lab1" class="form-control select2">
    <option value="">Seleccionar </option>
    <option value="Superi">1. Superi</option>
    <option value="Guerra">2. Guerra</option>
    <option value="RF Technologies">3. RF Technologies</option>
    <option value="Ricardo">4. Ricardo</option>
    <option value="Tecno-int">5. Tecno-int</option>
    <option value="Dyxa">6. Dyxa</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <label for="deliver">Fecha de Devolucion</label>
  <input type="text" name="deliver" id="deliver" class="form-control form-control-sm" required placeholder="Entrega al Cliente" readonly>
</div>


<div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <label for="change_type1">Tipo de cambio</label>
  <input type="number" step="00.01" name="change_type1" id="change_type1" class="form-control">
</div>


<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="cost_lab">Costo de laboratorio 1 (USD-O)</label>
  <input type="number" step="00.01" id="cost_lab" name="cost_lab" class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-2">
  <label for="cost_labARS">Costo de laboratorio 1 (ARS)</label>
  <input type="number" step="00.01" id="cost_labARS" name="cost_labARS" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Olvidaste cerrar el select:

```html
                     <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                          <label for="lab1">Laboratorio 1</label>
                          <select name="lab1" class="form-control select2" >
                          <option value="">Seleccionar </option>
                          <option value="Superi">1. Superi</option>
                          <option value="Guerra">2. Guerra</option>
                          <option value="RF Technologies">3. RF Technologies</option>
                          <option value="Ricardo">4. Ricardo</option> 
                          <option value="Tecno-int">5. Tecno-int</option>
                          <option value="Dyxa">6. Dyxa</option> 
                        </select> 
                        </div>
                          
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                          <label for="deliver">Fecha de Devolucion</label>
                          <input type="text" name="deliver" id="deliver" class="form-control form-control-sm" required placeholder="Entrega al Cliente" readonly>
                        </div>
                          
                          
                        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                          <label for="change_type1">Tipo de cambio</label>
                          <input type="number"   step="00.01" name="change_type1" id="change_type1"  class="form-control" >
                        </div>                    
                                      
                       
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                           <label for="cost_lab">Costo de laboratorio 1 (USD-O)</label>
                           <input type="number"   step="00.01" id="cost_lab" name="cost_lab" class="form-control"  >
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                          <label for="cost_labARS">Costo de laboratorio 1 (ARS)</label>
                          <input type="number"   step="00.01" id="cost_labARS" name="cost_labARS" class="form-control"  >
                        </div>
```